# How can I get a variable which contains an object with my model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a model, but I don't know how can I instanciate by using CI master controller. I know there is a way by using autoload in config or extend it, but I want this way.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Authentification {
function __construct() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('authentification_model');
    var_dump($this->authentification_model);
}
public function test() {    
}
```

}

Comment: You can add a private variable to the class and assign it with the model.

Comment: so, how can I get authentification_model?

Comment: you need to call it some where `new Authentification()`.It will not work as model because it does not extend CI_model.Even i guess its not inside model folder with same filename.

Comment: thanks guys, but i got it how it's working...